# how does context mobile detect module work?

Tags: 7

I cant find the documentation as to how to use the context mobile detect module. Is it used the same as the mobile detect module? With these parameters?

```
$detect = mobile_detect_get_object();
  $is_mobile = $detect->isMobile();
```

https://www.drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect  doesnt have any documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of [Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect).  The modules have two different goals.

Mobile Detect is primarily for coders, hence functions like `mobile_detect_get_object()`.  There is also support for using the detection rules via ctools (because I was developing a Panels based site at the time).  There is also some simple support for making this available in preprocess functions.

[Context Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect) creates mobile/tablet/desktop contexts (ie, it integrates with the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module).  So, if this is the approach you want to take, either use the Context UI for creating and using your contexts, or use the Context API in your own code.

Comment: Hi, Mobile detect is unpredictable when caching is on, which is why I am trying Context Mobile Detect , is that reliable with caching on?

Comment: I have added a context that is called mobile and made the reaction be that the section title is "mobile"  - how can I capture this in my code?

Comment: Context Mobile Detect has a solution for caching, but I don't know how well it works.  I have a patch on the issue (https://www.drupal.org/node/1889824) and have requested  that people test it out, but so far I have gotten no feedback.  Part of the reason for ctools/Panels support was to be able to use their caching solutions for variants on the same path.

Comment: @DianaCastillo Look into `context_active_contexts()`.  There is also an API.txt file in the module that you should look at.  Context is rather well documented on the net.

Comment: it still does not work with caching on .  Will installing the cache exclude module and not caching the particular pages where the mobile detection is necessary fix this problem?

Comment: @DianaCastillo Potentially.  If the problem is caching at the page level, then CacheExclude should do the trick (it essentially maintains a list of paths and other criteria, and then calls `drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);`.  If it involves other caches (like the block cache), then probably won't change things.

Comment: is there a way with code to turn the cache off of a block that I created in a module?

Comment: @DianaCastillo Starting to get off track here for the scope of you question, but it depends on where you want to change the block's cachability.  The proper way to change it is in a `hook_block_info_alter()` but that may not apply.